# Smartcasting to and from platform type in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using kotlin to create my adapter which extends `BaseAdapter` in android. below is the code inside `getView` method

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        var binding : ImageBinding
        var conView = convertView
        if(conView == null){
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context),
                    R.layout.image, parent, false)
            conView = binding.root;
            conView.tag = binding
        }else {
            binding = conView.getTag() as ImageBinding
        }

        return conView;
}
```

`conView.tag = binding` and `binding = conView.getTag()` is highlighted in a pink-like color.When i hover over `conView.tag = binding` with my mouse, a popup appears with a message **Smart cast to android.view.View!**. And when i hover over `binding = conView.tag`,a popup appears with a message **Smart cast to android.view.View**. Note the difference in the two messages where the latter is missing the platform type sign (!)

How can i implement the two suggested options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `convertView` is a nullable type variable(`View?`), `var conView = convertView` assigment creates a copy of a nullable `conView` variable. So you should handle `conView` variable as nullable.

Try the following way:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
    var binding : ImageBinding
    convertView?.let {
        binding = it.tag as ImageBinding
        return it
    }
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context), R.layout.image, parent, false)
    val conView = binding.root
    conView.tag = binding
    return conView
}
```

**Note**: Semicolons in Kotlin are not required, be aware of that

Comment: Parameters in kotlin are implicitly `val`, so assigning a new value to it will produce an error.

Comment: @Kiskae you are right, I have edited my answer properly

Comment: @AlexTa `View?` does not mean the view is optional but it means that the view can be null. kindly update your answer so that i can accept it.